# How to apply validations in angular 8. i am trying but it's not work properly

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<form> 
  <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="credentials.email" #email="ngModel" name="email" ngModel required>
  <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password" #password="ngModel" name="password" ngModel required>
  <button type="button" (click)="login()">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

if i click sign in button enter without any input then required field not working...i already try to solve this problem in another way but it's not work.
How i can apply validators?

Comment: Pleas read about how to use `reactive forms` in angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add  ngForm to your form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()" #heroForm="ngForm"> 
 <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="credentials.email" #email="ngModel" name="email" ngModel required>
 <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password" #password="ngModel" name="password" ngModel required>
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid" (click)="login()">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have mixed with reactive forms and template driven patterns. Stick to one approach and do it in respective way.

Reactive form: `https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms`
Template driven : `https://angular.io/guide/forms`
Validation : `https://angular.io/guide/form-validation`

Answer (score 0):

Using reactive-forms Try.

Please refer -> https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

`component.html` file.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginform"> 
  <input type="email" formControlName="email" ngModel required>
  <input type="password" formControlName="password" ngModel required>
  <button type="button" (click)="login()">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Add validation 
`component.ts` file.

```
loginform: FormGroup;

ngOnInit{

this.loginform = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7)]],
  });
}
```